# how to connect synology docker container postgresql and sonaqube

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, synology

How can i run in synology docker.

My local docker can run this command.

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube2 \
    -p 9001:9000 -p 9092:9092 \
    -e SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME='sona' \
    -e SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD='Naso!@0728' \
    -e SONAR_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://popo:5432/sona \
    --link popo:postgresql \
sonarqube
```

popo is my postgresql container's name .

that docker command can run my local docker engine. but synology docker container manage's can’t be run. how can i run?